# Base method gets called instead of derived method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am currently trying to deliver more than one implementation of an header file. I tried doing this like this:

```
// A.h:

class A {
    public:
        A();
        ~A();

        bool method1();
        bool method2();
}

// A.cpp: 
A::A() {
}

A::~A() {
}

bool A::method1() {
} 

bool A::method2() {
}

// B.h

class B : public A {
    public B();
    public ~B();

    bool method1();
    bool method2();
}

// B.cpp

B::B() {
}

B::~B() {
}

bool B::method1() {
    // actual code I want to use
}

bool B::method2() {
    // actual code I want to use
}

// AFactory.h

#define USE_B 10
#define USE_C 20

#define IMPL USE_B

class A;

class AFactory {
public:
    static A *getImplementation();
}

// AFactory.cpp

A *AFactory::getImplementation() {
#if IMPL == USE_B
    return new B();
#elif IMPL == USE_C
    return new C();
#else 
    return NULL;
#endif
}

// Test.cpp

int main () {
    A *test = AFactory::getImplementation();
    test->method1();
    test->method2();
}
```

The idea was, to deliver more than one implementation of the class A, which could be switched by simply changing the value of the define `IMPL`. The problem is, that the methods from the actual used implementation `B` are never called. The methods from the base class `A` are called instead. I tried to remove the A.cpp completly from the build, since it's never used or rather should never be used, but then it won't build, telling me, that I have undefined references in my test code.

Comment: Is that even compiling? As getImplementation returns a pointer..

Comment: Sorry, i'm really missing the namespaces in my presentation code. In the actual code they are present. The problem were missing `virtual` keywords in my interface, thanks to @Aesthete.

Comment: In C++ methods are not virtual by default, unlike in Java where they are unless you explicitly state not with final.

You will need test->method1(); test->method2()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override these methods, you use the `virtual` keyword.

```
class A
{
  virtual bool method1();
}

class B : public A
{
  virtual bool method1(); // If you want to override the base functionality.
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. The missing `virtual` keywords were the problem. So simple, yet so far away..

Comment: You're also not implementing any of the methods you defined in the header, that is the bigger issue.

Comment: Thanks. As I stated in a comment on the inital post, I just forgot the namespaces in my presentation code for SO.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that comment. Glad I could help.